# What proportion of the 240m area sensed by MODIS must be forest before it is defined as forest?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, landsat, reclassify, resampling

MOD12 is a MODIS product at 240m resolution. Landsat produces 30m resolution products, which I resampled to 240m resulting in a raster of proportion forest cover in each 240m pixel (based on the mean of the 8x30m cells it covers). The MOD12 raster has been reclassed to binary forest/non-forest.

My question is: what proportion of the 240m area sensed by MODIS must be forest before it is defined as forest? Is it majority (50%+) or something more complex? My reason for wanting to know this is to reclass the Landsat proportional raster to a binary raster that mirrors the MOD12 data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the detailed information about MOD12 data can be found in the [Algorithm Theoretical Basis Document (ATBD)](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/atbd/atbd_mod12.pdf). On page 23, it says that the forest classes require **>60% coverage** of the pixel.